# JS: Add a function with "prototype" not possible

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype, typeerror

I really can't find the problem. The Browser always gives the following error:

**TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._createButtons()')**

This is my code:

```
function OpenSlider(el, steps) {
  this.ul = el;
  this.steps = steps;
  this.slider_width = $(this.ul).width();
  this.content_width = this.ul.scrollWidth;
  this._createButtons();
}

OpenSlider.prototype = {
  _createButtons : function() {
    alert("created");
  }
}
```

And in another document:

```
var slider = OpenSlider(document.getElementById("element-id"),1);
```

Maybe you could help me...

Comment: try .... var slider = **new** OpenSlider(document.getElementById("element-id"),1);

Comment: Sometimes I'm really stupid... Thank you! :)

Comment: Unless you create a new instance, `this` inside the function will most likely be just `window`

Comment: Expending what @adeneo said, what you did was in fact putting `ul`, `steps` and co inside the global scope. This can lead to very, very strong headaches. I suggest looking up the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to new up the object with the OpenSlider constructor function:

```
var slider = new OpenSlider(document.getElementById("element-id"),1);
```

also change the line to:

```
OpenSlider.prototype._createButtons = function() {
    alert("created");
  };
```

as you are overwriting the prototype object instead of extending it with an additional function.